# How to suppress linting of valid useEffect instances?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, linter

This is valid `useEffect` code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.companyId !== undefined && state.companyId === -1) {
      return;
    }

    if (accessNotesRef.current) {
      accessNotesRef.current.focus();
    }

    if (vinRef.current) {
      vinRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, []);
```

In terms of dependencies, I very deliberately want it run only once upon load, thus the `[]`.  But the linter is complaining:

> React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'emailRef',
>   'lastNameRef', and 'state.companyId'. Either include them or remove
>   the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

So we have a case of a false positive.  Is there a way to suppress this?

Comment: Most linters have a way of suppressing warnings/errors of individual lines. Look at the docs for the linter you are using.

Comment: What linter do you use? This is a very specific question, not a generic one

Comment: @RaulRene: Sorry about that!  In VSCode on a Mac I use `ESLint` and `FlowLanguageSupport`.  But these aren't the ones outputting the messages in my Terminal session, are they?  I had assumed the messages were coming from some package utilized by `npm start`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your `useEffect` logic, and depending on how you initialized your `state`, you should do something like that:

```
/*
Example for handling the on mount
initialization through props or `useState`
*/
const App = props => {
  const [state] = useState(DEFAULT_INITIAL);
  const companyRef = useRef(props.DEFAULT_INITIAL);
  const myRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (
      companyRef.current.companyId &&
      DEFAULT_INITIAL.companyId &&
      DEFAULT_INITIAL.companyId !== -1 &&
      myRef.current
    ) {
      myRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, []);

  return <></>;
};
```

It is because **checking your state "on mount"**

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (state.companyId !== undefined && state.companyId === -1) {
    return;
  }
}, [])
```

is equivalent to checking the initial value of `useState` **or** using a reference when initializing your state through props.

And reference initialized with `useRef` doesn't need to be in the dep array as there is only once instance of them per component lifetime.

[image: Edit Q-58999058-useEffectExample]

Please refer to [React FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#performance-optimizations):

> **Is it safe to omit functions from the list of dependencies?**
>   Generally speaking, no.

If you are 200% sure that the linter is wrong, React still suggesting you to fix it.

If you are still into it, you can just disable the lint like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (state.companyId !== undefined && state.companyId === -1) {
    return;
  }
// eslint-disable-next-line
}, [])
```

Comment: I appreciate your clever way of using refs to remove the dependency warnings but I don't see that there is anything fundamentally wrong with my approach.  The root problem here is that the linter is giving a false positive warning about an empty dependency array.  And an empty dependency array is supposed to be completely valid with `useEffect`.

Comment: I added a FAQ from react docs, you can disable it if you are so sure about it, which I believe is strongly not recommended.